# Post Facebook message using Facebook Graph API with image containing tilde and ashx in url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use Facebook Graph API to post the messages on the user's wall with adding of all the message attributes (link, picture etc.) Everything had worked fine until I started to use this kind of urls:
http://feb.social.sc-demo.net/sitecore/shell/Applications/Social/Publishing/UI/~/media/Images/Penguins.ashx

I guess the fail happens because of using tilde or ashx extension, but I can’t avoid using of them.
Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could add your HTTP handler to your web config rather than using an ashx file. You can then format your URL's in a better way (i.e. using .jpg or .gif).

e.g.

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="/ImageHandler/*.jpg" type="MyLibrary.MyHandler, MyLibrary" validate="false"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Javascript API, you should try escaping your URL. Use `encodeURIComponent` around the URL.